# While conditions followed by ;

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I have been asked to comment some code and describe what it does. All was fine and I had a good handle on what was being done in the the cases of the switch but now I am unsure whether any of the cases are ever met. I don't have anyway to run or test this code currently as my main machine with all my regular software is down.

Does either of the cases of the switch get used besides the default with the conditions of this while loop? is i simply incremented to 32 and the rByte returned before it even makes the switch? What is with the ; after the conditions of the while? Shouldn't it be followed by {....} rather than ;  ?

```
while(pCommand[--Ptr.Five] > 10 && ++i <32);
if(i==32)
{
    return rByte;
}
switch(pCommand[Ptr.Five++])
{
    case 2: ... (lots of code)
           break;
    case 4: ...  (lots of cod)
           break;
    default: ...
           break;
}
```

Also, how is the --Ptr.Five handled vs. the Ptr.Five++? My understanding is the first moves the pointer back and uses that value while the second uses the current value and post increments.

Am I missing something? Even moving past the ; after the conditions of the while and the lack of {} after the while, wouldnt the value of Ptr.Five be > 10 and therefore never be 2 or 4 ever?

With the ; behind the conditions of the while, would i just get bumped to32 and the following if would return the rByte?

Comment: This code is dreadful. It this is an interview, find a different employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(pCommand[--Ptr.Five] > 10 && ++i <32);
```

doesn't have a body, but the loop condition itself has side-effects, so it *does* do something.

We could re-write this as:

```
while (1) {
    --Ptr.Five;
    if (pCommand[Ptr.Five] <= 10)
        break;
    ++i;
    if (i == 32)
        break;
}
if (i == 32) {
    /* we never hit the pCommand condition */
}
```

As for *why*:

- it searches backwards through `pCommand`, from offset `Ptr.Five` to at most 32 entries earlier, looking for a value `<= 10`
- if it doesn't find such a value within 32 entries, it returns `rByte`
- if it *does* find such a value, it switches on it and does some work

  - `PtrFive` is incremented to indicate the next entry after this value, *after* the switch is dispatched

---

> Also, how is the --Ptr.Five handled vs. the Ptr.Five++? My understanding is the first moves the pointer back and uses that value while the second uses the current value and post increments.

That's exactly correct. In:

```
pCommand[--Ptr.Five] > 10
```

`Ptr.Five` is decremented before the rest of the expression is evaluated, whereas in:

```
pCommand[Ptr.Five++]
```

the expression is evaluated with the *old* value of `Ptr.Five`, and then it's incremented right after. Here, that means the switch is based on the old entry in `pCommand` (the one that ended the while loop because it's `<= 10`), but `Ptr.Five` is incremented before code inside the cases executes.

---

A quick note on side-effects: as John Bode points out in a comment, my description of the pre-decrement and post-increment expressions isn't quite accurate.
This is because storing the new value into `Ptr.Five` *doesn't* have to happen right away.
However since it does have to happen (as if) by the next sequence point, which is here the `&&`, there's no real ambiguity.

This generally only becomes an issue if you string multiple interdependent side-effecting expressions together in a single statement. So, you know, try and avoid that.

Comment: "`Ptr.Five` is decremented before the rest of the expression is evaluated" -- this isn't quite true.  The *result* of the expression `--Ptr.Five` is the value of `Ptr.Five` minus one, but the *side effect* may not be applied before the rest of the expression has been evaluated.

Comment: The first `if (i == 32)` is wrong. The `while` loop iterates while `++i < 32`, so the break condition is `i >= 32`, not `==`.

Comment: No, `++i < 32` _pre-increments_ `i`, and then breaks the loop if the incremented value of `i` is no longer less than 32, ie, is equal to 32.

Answer (score 2):

The loop

```
while(pCommand[--Ptr.Five] > 10 && ++i <32);
```

decrements `Ptr.Five` and increments `i` until

- `pCommand[Ptr.Five] <= 10`, or
- `i >= 32`,

whichever happens first. Since the changes to the interesting variables are done in the loop condition, the loop body should be empty. (Not that it's particularly good style, but I've seen worse.)

If `i == 32`, the `switch` isn't reached, otherwise, if `i < 32`, you know that `pCommand[Ptr.Five] <= 10`, so both non-default cases can be reached.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon by itself is an empty statement. So doing e.g.

```
while (complicated_expression)
    ;
```

Is the same as:

```
while (complicated_expression)
{
}
```

It's often used when `complicated_expression` has side-effects, so no loop body is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer your question. Even if we assume that `i` starts at `0`, who knows what value `pCommand[Ptr.Five]` has at the start of this code block?

Addressing some of the questions that *can* be answered, would it help if we rewrote the `while` like this:

```
while(pCommand[--Ptr.Five] > 10 && ++i <32)
{
    /* do nothing as the body of the loop... nothing at all. 
     * Everything happens in the condition.
     */
}
```

The syntax with the semicolon is valid, if a bit confusing at first: think of what the semicolon means in C/C++ (terminates a statement) and then think of what the statement being terminates is in this case (hint: it's a "no operation").

The difference between `--Ptr.Five` and `Ptr.Five--` is what you describe: the first variant (the pre-decrement) will decrement `Ptr.Five` and then return the resulting value; the second variant (the post-decrement) will decrement the `Ptr.Five` but return the value *before* the decrement.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `i` started at `0` -- The while loop is parsing through 31 elements (1-31) of the `pCommand` array, decrementing `Ptr.Five` before checking the value, looking for a value that is less than `10`. If it does not find one, the function returns `rByte` -- it then checks the value of `pCommand[Ptr.Five]` **before** it increments... therefore, the value used in the switch is the same as the value used in the `while` conditional. The value could well be any of the switch conditions as we know it is less than `10`